# Codeigniter 404 Not Found Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi all I have been developing a site using CodeIgniter without any issue, I am now hoping to move my site and make it live so to speak, I have updated the base URL and can access my login page without an issue, I also inlcuded the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /livesystem/

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule (.*?)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule (.*?)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

however when I was working with localhost the following lines in CI would work without an issue:
redirect('main');

however when this runs on my live site I am receiving the following page back
Not Found

```
404 Not Found: The requested URL /livesystem/index.php was not found on this server.
```

I have checked that the index.php is infact within my codeigniter root folder and it is - has anyone got any ideas? - I guess this is something really simple that I have missed. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you set the `$config['base_url']` as your domain name
in .htaccess file change the last line as like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/index.php?$1 [L]
```

i will it's work

Comment: I will give it a try thanks for the suggestion - I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: could you give me an example htaccess for example if the base url was test.com/user1